# Classification of all unbiased estimators of the mean of a normal population

Tags: st.statistics

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim \text{i.i.d.} \operatorname N(\mu,\sigma^2).$ Consider these functions of the foregoing random variables:

- Any weighted average of $X_1,\ldots,X_n,$ with constant (i.e. non-random) weights not depending on $\mu$ or $\sigma^2.$
- $\operatorname{median}\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}.$ (If $n$ is even, take this to be the mean of the two middle observations.)
- $(\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} + \min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\})/2$
- $\operatorname{mean} \{X_i : i\in I\},$ where $I\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is randomly chosen from among all $2^n-1$ non-empty subsets, in a way that is independent of the values of $X_1,\ldots,X_n.$
- $\operatorname{mean} \{X_i : i\in I\},$ where $I\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is randomly chosen from among all $2^n$ subsets, in a way that does depend on $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ but for which this mean nonetheless has the properties stated below. (The third item in this list is a special case of this.)
- $\operatorname{median}\{X_i : i\in I \}$ with $I$ as in either of the last two situations above.

All of these functions of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ have the following properties:

- The value of each can be found without knowing the values of $\mu$ or $\sigma^2,$ i.e. each of these is a "statistic."
- Each has expected value $\mu$ regardless of the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2,$ i.e. each is an unbiased estimator of $\mu.$

**My question is** whether there is a way to classify all such functions. Can we describe some set of functions without mentioning anything about $\{\operatorname N(\mu,\sigma^2) : \mu\in\mathbb R, \sigma^2\in[0,+\infty)\}$ or any other family of probability distributions and show that those and only those have the properties stated in the last two bullet points above?

Comment: I suspect there are many more: for instance median(average($X_1,X_2$),average($X_3,X_4$))?

Comment: @jlewk : We took the median of an even number of numbers to be the mean of the two in the middle, so your example is just the mean of four of the random variables, and thus a special case of the very first example in my list. But you could take it one step further and look at $\operatorname{median}\big( (X_1+X_2)/2, \,\, (X_3+X_4)/2, \,\, (X_5 + X_6)/2 \big),$ and that would also do it.

Comment: Any function $f:R^n\to R$ such that $f(a+\vec{1} \mu) = f(a)+\mu$ for all reals $\mu$ and $f(x)=-f(-x)$ is going to work I believe. For instance is average$($first quartile,third quartile$)$ on the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\si}{\sigma} $At least in your setting, statistics (also called estimators) are random variables of the form $T(X)$, where $T$ is a Borel-measurable function from $\R^n$ to $\R$ and $X:=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$.

An estimator $T(X)$ of $\mu$ is called unbiased (for $\mu$) if
\begin{equation}
    E_{\mu,\si^2}T(X):=\int_{\R^n}dx\,T(x)f_{\mu,\si^2}(x)=\mu
\end{equation}
for all $(\mu,\si^2)\in\R\times(0,\infty)$, where $f_{\mu,\si^2}$ is the (joint) density of $X$, so that
\begin{equation}
    f_{\mu,\si^2}(x)=(2\pi\si^2)^{-n/2}\exp-\sum_1^n\frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{2\si^2}
\end{equation}
for $x:=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\R^n$.

E.g.,
\begin{equation}
    \bar X:=\frac1n\,\sum_1^n X_i
\end{equation}
is unbiased (for $\mu$).

So, $T(X)$ is unbiased for $\mu$ iff $E_{\mu,\si^2}(T(X)-\bar X)=0$ for all $(\mu,\si^2)\in\R\times(0,\infty)$ -- that is, iff the function $\R^n\ni x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto\bar x:=T(x)-\frac1n\,\sum_1^n x_i\in\R$ is orthogonal in $L^2(\R)$ to all the normal density functions $f_{\mu,\si^2}$, for all $(\mu,\si^2)\in\R\times(0,\infty)$.

This rather trivial characterization of unbiased estimators of $\mu$ for $N(\mu,\si^2)$ is apparently the least non-tautological characterization possible.

Indeed, the most comprehensive study of unbiased estimators is apparently the two-volume [book by Voinov and Nikulin](https://books.google.com/books?id=xgH1CAAAQBAJ&printsec=copyright#v=onepage&q&f=false). There is no non-tautological characterization of all unbiased estimators of any function of the parameter of **any** parametric family of distributions there.

In particular, in the long table of unbiased estimators of functions of the parameter $(\mu,\si^2)$ of the family of normal distributions, the only unbiased estimator of $\mu$ listed there is $\bar X$.

Indeed, all the other unbiased estimator of $\mu$ for the normal family do not really matter. Indeed, by the completeness, $\bar X$ is almost surely (a.s.) the only unbiased estimator of $\mu$ that is a function of a minimal sufficient statistic. So, by the [Blackwell--Rao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem)--[Lehmann–Scheffé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem#Completeness_and_Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_minimum_variance) theory, $\bar X$ is the (a.s. unique) uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator of $\mu$; actually, $\bar X$ is the best unbiased estimator of $\mu$ with respect to any convex [loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function).

Comment: "apparently the least non-tautological characterization possible" That doesn't quite make it to qualifying as an assertion. If it were something that can be proved, that would be more interesting.

Comment: @MichaelHardy : (i) I have fixed the link. (ii) Have you ever seen anywhere  a proof that an essentially non-tautological characterization of anything particular is impossible? Such a proof would require a mathematical definition of an essentially non-tautological characterization. That would be an exercise in mathematical logic, and to what useful ends in this case?

Comment: Previous comment continued: The answer provides two points: (I) that a nontrivial characterization of unbiased estimators of $\mu$ apparently does not exist in the literature and is apparently impossible and (II) such a characterization would hardly be useful, since $\bar X$ is the best estimator of $\mu$ according to a number of reasonable criteria. Indeed, how would you use such a characterization (and in what terms would you like the characterization to be)?

Comment: A theorem asserts that among all functions in the class of functions of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ that I describe in my question, one of them alone has the smallest variance. The purpose I had in mind, for which I would use an answer to this question, is just to understand how strong a claim that is.

Comment: And let us note that if you have a weighted average of two normal distributions with the same mean but somewhat different variances, then the sample median can have a smaller variance than the sample mean, and maybe some other member of this class of functions would be the unique one with smallest variance.

Comment: @MichaelHardy : "how strong a claim that is". What do you mean by that? As for the the mixture of two normal distributions, it would an entirely different problem.

Comment: An entirely different problem, you say, but a statistician must bear in mind that the question of whether a population is normally distributed or deviates somewhat from normality is always there and sometimes matters, and can be dealt with only by looking at what the data are saying.

Comment: As for "how strong a claim": If weighted average of the observations were the only functions that could serve as unbiased estimators, then it's not as strong a claim as if many exotic functions are also included.

Comment: Sometimes rather than having all of the observations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ available, one is handed only the sample median, the first and third sample quartiles, and the maximum and minimum. What is then the best estimator of $\mu\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: (i) Concerning your penultimate comment: if this is what you mean by "how strong", then $\bar X$ is the best in the strongest sense possible: the best among **all** unbiased estimators of $\mu$ whatsoever. (ii) Concerning your last comment: The answers to such questions are not available anywhere (to the best of my knowledge), and will probably be never be available. I would be more than extremely surprised otherwise. There are no answers to even much simpler questions of similar kinds.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Usually, what is covered by the Blackwell--Rao--Lehmann–Scheffé theory is very easy, and what is not covered by it is extremely hard or just impossible.